# Search algorithm is not working

Tags: ruby

I want to search a given number in this array filled with hashes:

```
Time_tables = [
  { name: 01251},
  { name: 05012},
  { name: 03232},
  { name: 02435},
  { name: 04545},
  { name: 03545}
]
```

My expected result is:

```
{name: 02435}
```

This is the code:

```
def finding_numbers(tables, train_number)
  tables.each do |i|
    if i[:name] == train_number
      p i
    end
  end
end

finding_numbers(Time_tables, 02435)
```

If I run this code, I get this:

```
{:name=>1309}
```

This number is not even in the array. What is going on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In ruby number literals starting with `0` are read as an octal representation:

```
puts 02435
# => 1309
```

So actually your code runs fine: it finds the correct element, it only writes the number decimally, and not octally

Comment: OP - you can use string representation of your number, other wise it will be converted to decimal always.

Comment: Did you face *StackOverflow* offline message sometimes back ? :-)

Comment: @ArupRakshit "id you face StackOverflow offline message sometimes back" what do u mean?

Comment: @YoniGeek Not you. I asked Uri. I tried to submit the same answer, got the *off-line message*. So I am asking if all people got the same or not.

Comment: @ArupRakshit Yes, stackoverflow was down for about a minute. It is happening frequently these days. They often claim they are attacked.

Comment: @UriAgassi You are lucky then.. :-)

Comment: @UriAgassi He hehe... OP: Check this for some bonus information - http://octathorpeweb.com/blog/2010/08/20/ruby-octal-integer-conversions/ .

Comment: @ArupRakshit 'Did you face StackOverflow offline message sometimes back ? :-) ' :) are u reading my twitter feed? funny I uploaded a png about it! :)

Comment: @YoniGeek No.. I have seen it in my browser itself.. ;)